# XML comparisons

Tags: java, xml, xmlreader

I've got an XML file where I need to get a specific elements in it, I'm having troubles to write the logic to get these elements.In my case i want to get all the values in the secondchild(parent = solution that is the root tag) the one having 505.9208295302417 Someone told me to use comparisons if statement to get the elements

my xmlfile

```html
 <problem>    
      <solution>
      <cost>505.9214355631349</cost>
       <routes>
            <route>
                 <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                 <vehicleId>1_1</vehicleId>
                 <start>0.0</start>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>5 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>109.9819741964403</arrTime>
                      <endTime>119.9819741964403</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <end>229.9639483928806</end>
            </route>
            <route>
                 <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                 <vehicleId>3_1</vehicleId>
                 <start>0.0</start>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>2 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>109.98268205388193</arrTime>
                      <endTime>119.98268205388193</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>1 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>119.98357684436793</arrTime>
                      <endTime>129.98357684436792</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>3 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>129.98449911991617</arrTime>
                      <endTime>139.98449911991617</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>4 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>139.98539391040217</arrTime>
                      <endTime>149.98539391040217</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <end>259.9672978232725</end>
            </route>
       </routes>
  </solution>
  <solution>
       <cost>505.9208295302417</cost>
       <routes>
            <route>
                 <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                 <vehicleId>1_1</vehicleId>
                 <start>0.0</start>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>5 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>109.9819741964403</arrTime>
                      <endTime>119.9819741964403</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <end>229.9639483928806</end>
            </route>
            <route>
                 <driverId>noDriver</driverId>
                 <vehicleId>3_1</vehicleId>
                 <start>0.0</start>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>4 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>109.98190391287031</arrTime>
                      <endTime>119.98190391287031</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>2 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>119.98282618841856</arrTime>
                      <endTime>129.98282618841856</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>1 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>129.98372097890456</arrTime>
                      <endTime>139.98372097890456</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <act type="service">
                      <serviceId>3 </serviceId>
                      <arrTime>139.9846432544528</arrTime>
                      <endTime>149.9846432544528</endTime>
                 </act>
                 <end>259.9668316441239</end>
            </route>
       </routes>
  </solution>
</problem>
```

logic given

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("solution");
Double requiredCost = 505.9208295302417;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {    
    Node solutionNode = nodeList.item(i);
    if (solutionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element solutionElement = (Element) solutionNode;
        Node costNode = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0);

        // if correct cost, proceed to parse further
        Double costValue = Double.valueOf(costNode.getTextContent());
        if (Double.compare(requiredCost, costValue) == 0) {
            // there you go, found the node with the cost 505.9208295302417
            // now just parse all the node elements you need here
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried to do is

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("solution");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node solutionNode = nodeList.item(i);
    if (solutionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element solutionElement = (Element) solutionNode;
        Node costNode = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("cost").item(0);
        Node routes = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("routes").item(0);
        // if correct cost, proceed to parse further
        Double costValue = Double.valueOf(costNode.getTextContent());
        if (Double.compare(requiredCost, costValue) == 0) {

            // there you go, found the node with the cost 505.9208295302417
            // now just parse all the node elements you need here
            System.out.println("DriverId : "
                    + solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("driverId")
                            .item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("vehicleId : "
                    + solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("vehicleId")
                            .item(0).getTextContent());

            NodeList optionList = solutionElement.getElementsByTagName("act");
            for (int j = 0; j < optionList.getLength(); ++j) {
                Element option = (Element) optionList.item(j);
                for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k) {
                    String optionText = option.getTextContent();
                    //address.add(optionText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]"," "));
                    System.out.println("Citizen :" + optionText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " "));
                }
                ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

updated currently using xpath

```
    package xpath;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

public class Xpath {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory Factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = Factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/solution.xml");

    //creating an XPathFactory:
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    //using this factory to create an XPath object: 
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

    // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("problem/solutions/solution[cost='505.9208295302417']/routes/route");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
System.out.println("test"+nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
        Element el = (Element) nodes.item(i);

        System.out.println("Element currently in: " + el.getNodeName());
        // seach for the Text children
        if (el.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            System.out.println("driverid:" + el.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
        Node vehicle = el.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();

        NodeList children = el.getChildNodes();

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can access all `route` tags descendants of //solution/cost with the desired value directly with xpath, then iterate those nodes to get the values.
Demo with xmllint utility

`xmllint --xpath '//solution[cost = "505.9208295302417"]/routes/route' test.xml`

```
<route>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
             <driverId>noDriver</driverId>                                                                                                                                                                    
             <vehicleId>1_1</vehicleId>                                                                                                                                                                       
             <start>0.0</start>                                                                                                                                                                               
             <act type="service">                                                                                                                                                                             
                  <serviceId>5 </serviceId>                                                                                                                                                                   
                  <arrTime>109.9819741964403</arrTime>                                                                                                                                                        
                  <endTime>119.9819741964403</endTime>                                                                                                                                                        
             </act>                                                                                                                                                                                           
             <end>229.9639483928806</end>                                                                                                                                                                     
        </route>
<!-- more route tags here -->
```

Comment: yes that what i turn into, I got the desire child but now how to iterate through?

Comment: On java, you will get a Nodelist or similar to iterate.

Comment: I've made a for loop then use System.out.println("test"+nodes.item(i).getTextContent());

Comment: i got all the data but now i would like to store it in variables, such as for vehicleid etc.. any idea? just learned xpath 30mins ago please help

Comment: You can get specifics inside you loop with `nodes.item(i). getElementsByTagName("vehicleId")
                            .item(0).getTextContent())`, get the idea?.

Comment: getElementByTagName not recognized please check above i've updated my codes

Comment: There's plenty of examples on how to parse XML, take your time to do some research on your own. You have now a good starting point.